# pyinstaller makes the executable object based on a python program but at starting delivers errors

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.7

I wanted to make a portable version of PictureFrame2020.py, so that my friends, without spyder3 and python knowledges can use it too. Unfortunately the executable (Pyinstaller) PictureFrame object delivers Errors like these:

```
WARNING:pi3d.Display:create Display with (...use_glx=True) for transparent background on x11 window. libGLX needs to be available Traceback (most recent call last): File "pi3d/Shader.py", line 192, in _load_shader File "pkg_resources/init.py", line 1167, in resource_string File "pkg_resources/init.py", line 1412, in get_resource_string File "pkg_resources/init.py", line 1579, in _get File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 344, in get_data FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEI8C34IS/pi3d/shaders/std_head_vs.inc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "PictureFrame_2MI_My.py", line 1194, in File "pi3d/Shader.py", line 149, in create File "pi3d/Shader.py", line 110, in init File "pi3d/Shader.py", line 97, in make_shader File "pi3d/Shader.py", line 199, in _load_shader File "pi3d/Shader.py", line 195, in _load_shader FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'std_head_vs.inc' [2394] Failed to execute script 'PictureFrame_2MI_My' due to unhandled exception!
```

I wood be very thankfull if somebody could help me

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not all submodules(of pi3d) and datas were taken into consideration at building by pyinstaller the executable object. So I tried to add to the options: --collect all    and finally worked.
Perhaps it would have been sufficiant --collect submodules but I am satisfied with the result. Programs start sometimes much slower as in spyder3 but important is they start.